# Pass geolocation JavaScript values to a Bean

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, geolocation

I have to pass geolocation values got by using html5 geolocation to my managed bean ItemMb, here is my code to clarify things and i don't really know how to achieve this.

My managed bean

```
public class ItemMb {

    private Item item = new Item();

    // get/set
}
```

My dto Item

```
public class Item {

//  private Double idCollect;
    // login et password
    private Double lat;
    private Double lon;
    private Double accuracy;
    private String photo;
    private String remark;

    public Item(){
    }
// getters and setters
```

Here is my .js file where i got geolocations values and innertext them in some primefaces tags

```
window.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position){              

      document.getElementById("xCurrentPosition").innerHTML = (Math.round(position.coords.latitude*100) / 100);
      document.getElementById("yCurrentPosition").innerHTML = (Math.round(position.coords.longitude*100) / 100);
      document.getElementById("accuracyCurrentPosition").innerHTML = position.coords.accuracy;    

      });
```

Now i want to pass those JavaScript generated geolocation values to my managed bean ItemMb. If you need more informations feel free to ask.

Comment: How are you firing the request to the server to initialize the managed bean: through a GET request by changing the current URL or through an ajax request?

Comment: throught a GET request, for my page navigation i use prettyfaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've finally found the answer, i will let it there in case if someone has the same problem.
You have to follow these steps:

1)  Define a primefaces remoteCommand

> ```
> <p:remoteCommand name="myRemoteCommand" process="@this" autoRun="false" actionListener="#{myMb.myListener}"/>
> ```

2)  Call the command in your JavaScript code

> ```
> myRemoteCommand ([{name:'paramName1',   value: 'paramValue1'}, {name:'paramName2',     value: 'paramValue2'}, …]);
> ```

3)  In the backing bean use this method

> ```
> void myListener(){
>                 String param1 = (String) FacesContext.getInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("paramName1");
>                 …
> }
> ```

Comment: Should't the method be: getCurrentInstance()?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the JavaScript code in the HTML5 application. i've tested it works.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

    //lon      
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;

    //lat
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;

    //alert(lon+", "+lat);



    });
```

Comment: That's not what i want unfortunally:p In my code i already display those value , but what i want is to store those  geolocation value as data from my Item, i would like to set lon, lat and accuracy into Item property

Comment: but you do not want to in html5? i see from you code in java or android or so

Comment: I want to pass those values to my managed bean because I need to make a POST request in my Java code